# I get some error when create new model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite3-python

I created 2 model for one to one in Django model

So model codes is very simple

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CutkG.png)

I executed CMD after put the above code
python manage.py migrate
But I get this error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmI3F.png)`

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Edit the question and add all the code, output, and error messages as plain text.

Comment: You need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` first like the error says?

Comment: Looks like django is telling you exactly what to do: Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and THEN `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Thanks @Gameplay
I executed 
python manage.py makemigrations 
and then 
python manage.py migrate
So It is working fine now.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Always after running `create model` in Django apply the below commands in sequence:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`
3. `python mange.py runserver`

You should also add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` section of `settings.py` file for which you are applying the migrations.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',        
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned you should copy/paste the error and not add it as a picture. You can edit your question.

As you can see in the error message, you need to create migrations (in the terminal you type: python manage.py makemigrations) then you'll need to run them (with python manage.py migrate) then you'll need to restart your server with (python mange.py runserver). This should solve your issue!